# Neo4j connection failing - Bitnami AWS

Tags: python, neo4j, bolt

I've trying to connect to a remote Neo4j instance via the python driver. I'm using python 3.7 and the most up to date version of the driver. I have no issues connecting via the browser and I get this:

```
bolt://<address>:7687
```

No issues but when I try the same address with the driver I get:

```
neobolt.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 
Cannot to connect to Bolt service on ('<address>', 7687) 
(looks like HTTP)
```

Conf settings are:

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be that the Neo4j instance is behind a load balancer that only accepts HTTP requests. You have to change ports and add your own cert to make it work.